# Ask a user for file name, then pass that file name as argument?

Tags: python, user-input, filenames

My assignment was given as follows:

Write a function that writes a series of random numbers to a file. Each random number should be in the range of 1 through 500. The application should let the user specify how many random numbers the file will hold.

Write another function that reads the random numbers from the file, display the numbers, and then displays the following:
•   The number of random numbers read from the file
•   The sum of the numbers
•   The average of the numbers
•   The largest number generated
•   The smallest number generated

Write a main function that does the following:
•   Asks the user to enter a file name to write the random numbers to
•   Pass the file name as an argument when you call the function that writes the numbers to a file
•   Pass the file name as an argument when you call the function that reads the numbers from a file

My code looks like this:

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np

def main():
    myfile = input("Enter 'filename.txt' here ")
    with open(myfile, 'w+') as f:
        rand_gen()

    return f
    myfile.close

    disp_stats()

def rand_gen():
    for count in range(int(input('How many random numbers should we use?'))
    line = str.random.randint(1,500))
    myfile.write(str.line +'\n'))

def disp_stats():
    myfile = open(f,"r")
    total = 0
    count = 0
    print('The numbers are: ')
    for line in myfile:
        number = int(line)
        total += number
        count +=1
        print(number)

    average = total / count
    data = np.loadtxt(f)
    print('The count is ',count,)
    print('The sum is',total,)
    print('The average is ',format(average, '.2f'))
    print('The minimum value is ',format(np.min(data), '.0f'))
    print('The maximum value is ',format(np.max(data), '.0f'))
    myfile.close

main()
```

I can get the rand_gen and disp_stats functions to write and read to/from a specified file (eg, random.txt). But I can't figure out how to pass on a file name based on user input. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables as method arguments as follows:

```
def main():
    // get input from user
    rand_gen(my_file);

def rand_gen(file_name):
    // here you can use the parameter file_name
```

I suggest you to take a look at some basic concepts like parameters, variables, variable scopes etc.

https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php

Comment: This was extremely helpful, I am very new to programming (obviously). Thank you, beautiful internet stranger.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the file name from user and pass that to the functions. Then pass the file name to open()

```
def main():
    file_name = str(input("Enter file name ")
    rand_gen(file_name)

def rand_gen(file_name):
    my_file = open(file_name, mode='w+')
    # perform operations here
    my_file.close()
```